# Телефон не может подключиться к серверу socket.io

Tags: node.js, reactjs, socket.io

Использую NodeJS + ReactJS + Socket.io.
С ПК все отлично работает, но при заходе на сайт с телефона, не хочет подключаться.
Порт 7777, ssl
[image: скриншот логов с телефона]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно было использовать нормальный SSL сертификат